# Reading specific frames from video file with .NET (not necessarily in sequential order)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, video, opencv

I have a .NET Winform application and i need to show specific frames of a video file. Frames aren't necessarily in sequential order and are loaded when the user moves a slider, or when the application fires some events. I tried the following things:

1. **Using EmguCV (OpenCV Wrapper)**: The problem here is that when i use SetCaptureProperty (With CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, AVI_RATIO or MSEC ) to sets capture's position, **the position isn't seted correctly** (I checked it using GetCaptureProperty next to the SetCaptureProperty instruction). So, the frame returned by QueryFrame isn't the needed frame.
2. **Using WPF MediaElement** with Clock driven behavior: I can set the position of the video at the place that i need. The problem is that **i don't know how get only one frame of the video sequence**. By default, i have the Clock controller paused. When I set the position, If I call Clock.Controller.Resume(), then the video start playing from here. If I don't call Clock.Controller.Resume(), or if i call Clock.Controller.Resume() and then Clock.Controller.Pause() nothing is happening.
3. Im looking for **another video library** that can be used for accomplish this work, but i am not sure about what could be used. Any idea?

Thanks a lot for all comunity members, not only for help with this answer, but for the very big help that you give me with my problems every day. Iam new, but i would try to return these helping others with your problems.

*Sorry for my terrible english! (Im spanish speaker and english speaking is not my best quality :S)*

Comment: Try this approach, it worked for me hace tiempo: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13237/Extract-Frames-from-Video-Files

Comment: Thank you very much Diego! I tried to use this solution but it isn't mpeg codec compatible. I forgot remark that the solution must give support for this kind of file. Anyway, thanks a lot!